# Why do findById method of a seuqelize model called both "then" and "catch"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js, koa

So I'm trying to use the passport-jwt with Sequelize model, and parse the user.id to an existing model in database. 
The result is quite not what I have expected, it gives me a "headers have already been sent" error, which indicates that the passport-jwt has already sent the "Not found" to my client (which is just a curl with header given)

```
curl http://10.0.0.39/api/secure -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrb21tZW50anMuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE3MTY1MDkzLCJleHAiOjE1NDg3MDEwOTMsImF1ZCI6Ind3dy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEyMyJ9.s1r6jkqBGZ8cAYEWdsvRVjHNohj2-aYzo-S_TH_2gAI"
```

The response on this sideis 
`Not Found`

The sample code is attached below. The debug log indicate that the code actually called both ".then" clause and the ".catch" clause.

Where do I make mistake?

```
import * as passportJwt from "passport-jwt"
import {config} from "../../config"
import {models} from "../../database"
import {logger} from "../../logger"
import { UserInterface, UserModel } from "../../models/user";
const jwtOptions: passportJwt.StrategyOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: passportJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt"),
    secretOrKey: config.jwt.secret,
    issuer: config.jwt.issuer
};
let jwtStrategy = new passportJwt.Strategy(jwtOptions, async (payload,done)=>{
    models.user.findById(parseInt(payload.sub)).then((user: UserInterface | null)=>{
        if (user){
            console.log("user found");
            return done(null,user,payload);
        } else {
            console.log("user not found");
            return done(null,false,payload);
        }    
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
        return done(err,false,null);
    });
})
export {jwtStrategy}
```

the debug log is like the following:

```
info: Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "isPrimary", "notificationList", "subscriptionList", "moderationList", "siteList", "connections", "avatar", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."id" = 123; logging=function (msg) {
      // build argument list (level, msg, ... [string interpolate], [{metadata}], [callback])
      var args = [level].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
      target.log.apply(target, args);
    }, plain=true, raw=false, where="user"."id" = 123, rejectOnEmpty=false, hooks=true, attributes=[id, username, isPrimary, notificationList, subscriptionList, moderationList, siteList, connections, avatar, createdAt, updatedAt], tableNames=[users], type=SELECT, model=class extends Model {}
```

user not found 
error 
{ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: headers have already been sent
        at Object.set status [as status]

---

updated: tried with a different version, but use Promise style call to sequelize instead, still the same problem here.

```
let jwtStrategy = new passportJwt.Strategy(jwtOptions, (payload,done)=>{
    models.user.findOne({where: {id: parseInt(payload.sub)}}).then((result: UserInterface | null)=>{
        if (result){
            console.log("user found");
            return done (null, result, payload);
        } else {
            console.log("user not found");
            return done (null, false, "not found");
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
        return done(null, false, {message: err.message});
    })
})
```

Comment: First off, the `headers have already been sent` is a sign of you trying to send two responses for the same request.  It's possible that `.then()` gets called on the first time through this code and `.catch()` is called on the second time through.

Comment: Second, you can get both `.then()` and `.catch()` called if there's an exception thrown in the `.then()` handler which will change the promise to rejected and then call a subsequent `.catch()` handler.  For example, if `return done (null, false, "not found");` throws an exception for any reason (such as `done()` isn't defined or isn't a function).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm not quite sure about what's actually going wrong, since I did another few modify in the middleware after this and find it's not the problem in koa-js. Maybe it's just a problem of passport-jwt.